# How can i call php script that i have on my website in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to call a PHP script on my web server like this:

```py
import subprocess


def SaveScore():
    subprocess.call("php https://example.com/newrecord.php?name=ivan&record=123")


SaveScore()
```

This isn't working. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your website hosted on a webserver. `php` will not work.

You should try the `requests` module of python

```py
import requests as r

response = r.get("https://example.com/newrecord.php?name=ivan&record=123")
body = response.text

print(body)
```